# How do I install JQuery into my web app using Maven?

Tags: maven-2, maven, maven-3

I am looking at using Maven 3 for some web development. I know how to use maven to resolve java based jar files. How do I use maven to resolve JavaScript dependencies for example I want to have maven automatically put jquery in my webapp/js folder?

Is it possible to do transative JavaScript dependencies with Maven 3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create your own "war" that has jquery in it on the path you specified.

Afterwards add that war to your real web application. Maven should merge it. I think it was called somehting like "processing overlay".

I'm using the same for some GWT application where the javascript is generated by a maven plugin and it works well.

Comment: How do I add the war to my project using maven? Can I make transitive JavaScript dependencies?

Comment: You add it as a dependency of type war. Before you can add it to your other projects you need a web project with jquery in it and install it to your repository.

Comment: Overlay documentation http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/war-overlay.html

Comment: That link indeed explains the behavior I was refering to. I've looked at it some time ago. :)

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps [WebJars](http://www.webjars.org/) can help you:

> [WebJars](http://www.webjars.org/) are client-side web libraries (e.g. jQuery & Bootstrap) packaged into JAR (Java Archive) files.
>
> - Explicitly and easily manage the client-side dependencies in JVM-based web applications
> - Use JVM-based build tools (e.g. Maven, Gradle, & SBT) to download your client-side dependencies
> - Know which client-side dependencies you are using
> - Transitive dependencies magically appear

Caveat: WebJars does not put the jquery files in the `webapp/js` folder. Please read [documentation](http://www.webjars.org/documentation) to see how it is used with some popular frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your pom.xml file. It worked for me :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.efsavage.jquery</groupId>
    <artifactId>jquery-maven</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.2</version>
</dependency>
```

This library gives you a way to drop jQuery into your project as a Maven dependency, which means you don't have to include these third party files in your own source control.

Source : [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.efsavage.jquery/jquery-maven/1.7.2)

Comment: Hello, how do you use it in your JSP after you have added the dependency?

Answer (score 0):

May be you should use one of [CDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) to include external javascript libs to your webapps?
E.g. for jQuery you can simple include it from any of URLs from   http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery#CDN_Hosted_jQuery

Also libs from CDN will reduce your server bandwidth usage.

Comment: hosting from a CDN is not appropriate for this application, the application must be self contained with everything that it needs inside of it

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new zip artifact in your repo with your version of jquery inside.

Then use the maven war plugin to deploy it to your war.

Take a close look at `<targetPath>` and `<includes>` to be sure to deploy what you need where you need it :)

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <configuration>
       <overlays>
          <overlay>
             <groupId>yourgroupid</groupId>
             <artifactId>yourJqueryArtifactId</artifactId>
             <type>zip</type>
             <targetPath/>
             <includes>
                <include>js/jquery.js</include>
             </includes>
          </overlay>
       </overlays>
    </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

the previous config supposes that you have a directory called 'js' in your zip with jquery.js inside. It will be unzipped in your war at js/jquery.js

More info [here](http://kill3.wordpress.com/2008/06/10/managing-javascript-libraries-as-maven-war-overlays/)